# Use `Control` Data Type and `Imports Systems.Windows.Forms` together in a VB Page

Tags: vb.net, controls

I want to use `Control` data type and 'Systems.Windows.Forms` (to display VB messagebox) together in a single page.

But it is showing error at the `Control` data type.

1> Why?
2> How can I avoid this confliction?

Comment: Please post the code that is giving you an error. From what you have written I cannot conclude what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Please also post the error!